# How the define the y-axis as time of the day in kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a way to plot a scatter chart of traces having an x-axis as day and a y-axis as a time of a day (breaking the trace timestamp into date part and time part)?

Essentially what I want to achieve is a chart showing me at what time of a day specific traces are written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hourofday` and `dayofmonth` functions to split the date and render a scatter chart.

Here's a short example:

[Run query](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUBY0SK4WUxJLUkszcVE2FaC4FIFAyMjAy0DU00DUwVDAwtTIwACIlHUwpMxxSRnilzOFSsVw1CqkVJal5KQouiZUKtkCHVOan5ebnlWRolGjqKGTklxblpwEFgTyg0iKgwtQiheLkxJKS1KLkjMSiEgCvVrkgyAAAAA==)

```
datatable (t: datetime) [
    "2020-10-01 05:00:00",
    "2020-10-01 06:00:00",
    "2020-10-02 06:00:00",
    "2020-10-02 07:00:00",
]
| extend Day = dayofmonth(t), hourofday(t)
| render scatterchart
```